# In JAVA, is it possible to print something in super class method, and override and add more information to it in sub class?

Tags: java, overriding, subclass, superclass

```
public class superA {
    public void display() {
        System.out.println("In super class superA");
    }
}

public class subB extends superA {
    @Override
    public void display() {
        System.out.println("In sub class subB");
    }
}

public class subC extends superA {
    @Override
    public void display() {
        System.out.println("In sub class subC");
    }
}
```

If an object of sub class subB calls display method, it should give output like:
(new line)In super class superA
(new line)In sub class subB

Comment: have you heard of the 'super' keyword?

Comment: I didn't, but, thanks for suggesting that @Stultuske

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method names of all the classes parent and child is same, when you want to override superclass/parent class method with same name in child class you have to use super keyword.

Comment: To override a method in subclass "super" keyword isn't necessary.  And, do read comments on the questions before posting your answer :)

Answer (score -1):

```
public class superA {
    public void display() {
        System.out.println("\nIn super class superA");
    }
}

public class subB extends superA {
    @Override
    public void display() {
        super.display();
        System.out.println("\nIn sub class subB");
    }
}

public class subC extends superA {
    @Override
    public void display() {
        super.display();
        System.out.println("\nIn sub class subC");
    }
}
```

Comment: Code-only answers are not very good. Can you provide some simple explanation of what you changed and why?

Comment: This won't work! My main query was to print super class as well as sub class method information. Whether it's on new line or not doesn't matter much!

Comment: just try it and you will wonder that it works :) just  new subC().display()